# Route53 HostedZoneTags vs regular tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

When you create a Route 53 Hosted zone via Cloudformation, you can specify `HostedZoneTags`. Do these differ in any ways from regular tags set with Cloudformation?

Comment: By the way I noticed that `HostedZoneTags` does not seems to create the tags to my hosted zone. But I have no errors in my CloudFormation template. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloudformation Tag type enables you to specify a key-value pair that can be used to store information about an AWS CloudFormation stack.

The HostedZoneTags property describes key-value pairs that are associated with an `AWS::Route53::HostedZone` resource.

Comment: Yes, but what about this: "All stack-level tags, including automatically created tags, are propagated to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports" (from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html)